# knitr - multiple plots within a for loop with grid.arrange

Tags: r, knitr, pdflatex

I am new to knitr so I am trying to modify the example given at http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/externalization/ to be used with my own r-script.  Everything seems to work ok except for a piece of code where the following lines are performed:

```
for (j in seq(1,length(kkkk)-1))
{
 q1=qplot(x[seq(kkkk[j],kkkk[j+1]),1],x[seq(kkkk[j],kkkk[j+1]),2])
 q2=qplot(x[seq(kkkk[j],kkkk[j+1]),1],x[seq(kkkk[j],kkkk[j+1]),6])
 q3=qplot(x[seq(kkkk[j],kkkk[j+1]),1],x[seq(kkkk[j],kkkk[j+1]),9])
 grid.arrange(q1,q2,q3,ncol=1)
}
```

Those lines will create a series of figures and I would like very much to see them in the final report. Unfortunately nothing shows up. I read the other threads on a similar subject and one of the suggestions was to use print.  Unfortunately that also did not force the figures to show up (I have used print(grid.arrange ...)  which returns NULL).

Any suggestions?

Many thanks.

Comment: @konvas Many thanks for the reply. No, I do not have a pdf("filename.pdf").  How would the .Rnw file know the file names to be added to the final pdf report? I have used the following line in the Rnw file - <<Q1,warning=FALSE,fig.width=11, fig.height=9, out.width='1.0\\linewidth'>>=
@.  Such a line calls the piece of code you see above.

Comment: Just an update - it seems that graphics.off() in the beginning of a r-script blocks qplot and grid.arrange. I have commented the line graphics.off() and the figures are now shown on the final pdf document.